# DOCX to RTF without Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: openxml, docx

Can I convert a docx file in c# program, to RTF without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?

Maybe with Openxml library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking into this, myself, and so far I'm leaning toward the conclusion that it's not possible without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll or [a similar](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/richtextbox.aspx) [third-party](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) component to do the conversion.

The OpenXML library is great for reading / writing to a `.docx` file, but the format conversion would have to make use of the Word engine itself.